# How to bind dropdown control in edit mode?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am having a list of country along with its corresponding states.

Now i want to bind the country and state value in dropdown control when open in edit mode.

This is the fiddler link:

http://jsfiddle.net/mariapithia/4yj8rprp/9/

```
     <tr data-ng-repeat="friend in friends">
                        <td><strong>{{ friend.Id }}</strong></td>
                        <td>
                        <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{ friend.firstname}}</p>
                        <input data-ng-show="friend.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="friend.firstname" />


                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{ friend.lastname}}</p>
                        <input data-ng-show="friend.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="friend.lastname" />

                        </td>

                      <td>
                      <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{ friend.Country.Name }}</p>
                          @*How do i use select here for dropdown for binding country name in my dropdown*@
                @*<select data-ng-show="friend.editMode">
                    <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
                 </select>  *@
                        </td>
                        <td>
                       <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{friend.State.Name }}</p>
@*How do i use select here for dropdown for binding state name in my dropdown*@
                @*<select data-ng-show="friend.editMode">
                    <option value="">-- Select State--</option>
                 </select>  *@
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p ><a data-ng-click="toggleEdit(friend)" href="javascript:;">Edit</a> | <a data-ng-click="deletefriend(friend)" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

**Like i have use textbox for displaying firstname and lastname.sameway i would like to use dropdown for displaying my country name and state name in dropdown and allow user to select other country and state too from dropdown if user wants to select**.

I have taken code from this link with slight addition of fields:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/crud-operations-in-mvc-5-using-webapi-with-angularjs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you wanted you could use ng-options for both select box for states & countries.

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{ friend.Country.Name }}</p>
    <select data-ng-show="friend.editMode" ng-model="friend.Country" ng-options="country.Name for country in countries track by country.Id "></select>
</td>
<td>
    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{friend.State.Name }}</p>
    <select data-ng-show="friend.editMode" ng-model="friend.State" ng-options="state.Name for state in states track by state.Id "></select>
</td>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.countries = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "America",
}, {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Australia",
}, {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "london",
}];

$scope.states = [{
    Id: 1,
    CountryId: 1,
    Name: "Chicago",
}, {
    Id: 2,
    CountryId: 2,
    Name: "sydney",
}, {
    Id: 3,
    CountryId: 3,
    Name: "abc",
}];
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yj8rprp/11/)**

> **Note**
>
> Used track by id for selecting option on load as suggest in this
>   [**github issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1302)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73301/discussion-between-maria-pithia-and-pankajparkar).

Comment: @MariaPithia sorry to say, but i can't join chat now :(

Comment: ok no problem but just see the code i have sent you in chat thats it and then please edit your dropdown code for state as because i am facing problem in binding state dropdown only(country dropdown is bind correclty with your code).so just see the code only that i have sent u in chat

Comment: I'm curious to know why you are fetching state and country list while he click on edit, why you don't get them at start load of your controller

Comment: oh ok so you are telling that on load of controller i need to fetch once country and state and use it on edit method too but if yes still how would you bind state dropdown??

Comment: allitem[
{
       "Id": 1,
       "Name": "Australia",
       "State": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Name": "Sydney"
           }

}]

Comment: your state dropdown will become like this`<select data-ng-show="friend.editMode" ng-model="friend.State" ng-options="state.Name for state in allItems track by state.Id "></select>`, why you don't separate countries and states as i did in my plunkr

Comment: i am getting response in this way.getting country and state in method only

Comment: but for that i have to make two calls to my server side and i dont want that so i have done in one call only

Comment: ya it'd be great if you will do two separate calls, that will not make any performance issue

Comment: yaa ok i thought like making two seperate calls would be performance issue.but still could you provide me any solution for my current situation as because it would be great for me to learn.please

Comment: country contains states array, are all the states inside country array belong that country only or they are of all countries?

Comment: structure of array is like this:allitem[ { "Id": 1, "Name": "Australia", "State": [ { "Id": 1, "Name": "Sydney" } }].yes array of state is inside array of country

Comment: it could be something like http://jsfiddle.net/4yj8rprp/11/ , partially working..

Comment: hey it is the same solution as u have describe in 1 of your comment.u have taken country and state array seperately.i was telling make country array with its corresponding states array like i have given in my previous comment

Comment: @MariaPithia Sorry to say, just a note I can't help you thoroughly to get the output, I could only give direction to you,

Comment: yaa ok no problem.i have tried this:<select data-ng-show="friend.editMode" ng-model="friend.Country"
                        ng-options="country.Name for country in allItems track by country.Id ">

Comment: allItems  is an array which contains country and corresponding states of country

Comment: You could open another question so that other people also help you

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-repeat

```
<select data-ng-show="friend.editMode" ng-model="friend.Country.Name">
    <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country}}" ng-selected="friend.Country.Name==country">{{country}}</option>
</select>
```

Or use ng-options

```
<select ng-model="friend.Country.Name" ng-options="country as country for country in countries"></select>
```

In your controller define an array of countries.

```
$scope.countries = ['America', 'Australia', 'london'];
```

Comment: should i update my angular version so that you can use ng-options?

Comment: Not necessary, ng-options is just a fancier way of writing ng-repeat.  However, there are many other good stuff that comes with Angular 1.3 so you may want to upgrade to that, just keep in mind there is no i.e8 support for it.

Comment: but still can you please please provide me the solution with ng-options and with my array structure.

Comment: Added, btw I think you might have the ability to use ng-options in your current one so I might have made a mistake there, so give it a try.

Comment: can you create a chat so that we can discuss.please